# javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: error:1e000065:Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_DECRYPT

Tags: aes, android-keystore

I'm storing AES decryption key in AndroidKeyStore to decrypt data from SQLiteDB. Unfortunately, sometimes I get this error (Any android device and any API) rarely.

I would like to know what exactly this error means.
`javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: error:1e000065:Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_DECRYPT`.

Where I can find list of these `error:*`?

Comment: this error is caused by a mismatch between the keys used for encryption and decryption. make sure the keys are the same. I experienced this error after the encryption device was using the default key instead of pulling from server.

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @Manny265 I have used DefaultDataSourceFactory class provided by exoplayer. Inside Mainfirst below properties, I'm getting for EXT-X-KEY.  I think Exoplayer will automatically take the description key and decrypt the content. 
#EXT-X-KEY:
METHOD=AES-128,
URI="https://d.akamaized.net/th/encrypted/none/d9/p4/serve.key?
aka_me_session_id=A3l1dtjW"
#EXTINF:10.000000,
Please let me know if i'm missing anything.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, because I've initialised `cipher` for `ENCRYPT_MODE`, but before I've called `doFinal` for encrypt, I've re-initialised same `cipher` for `DECRYPT_MODE` in another place. So, there haven't to be same *race condition* and that could be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Decryption seems to work differently in Android from default Java Code in backend. In my case I was getting this error cause. Re-encoding the value of IV and SecretKey as UTF-8.

I was converting the KEY and IV like below and I was causing string to re-encoded.

```
val ivParameterSpec = IvParameterSpec(iv.toByteArray(charset("utf-8")))
val secretKeySpec = SecretKeySpec(key.toByteArray(charset("utf-8")), "AES")
```

I removed the "UTF-8" part cause it's in default converted as "UTF-8" no need to pass it again.

```
val ivParameterSpec = IvParameterSpec(iv.toByteArray())
val secretKeySpec = SecretKeySpec(key.toByteArray(), "AES")
```

(Note: Length of encryptedData is 128. IV and Key lengths are 16. Which are all divisible by 16 as algorithm needed.)

Full-code is below.

```
 fun decrypt(encryptedData: String, iv: String, key: String): String? {
        try {
            //IV & Key Generation
            val ivParameterSpec = IvParameterSpec(iv.toByteArray())
            val secretKeySpec = SecretKeySpec(key.toByteArray(), "AES")

            val c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING")
            c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec)

            val decodedValue = Base64.decode(encryptedData, Base64.URL_SAFE)
            val decValue = c.doFinal(decodedValue)

            return String(decValue)

        } catch (ex: IllegalBlockSizeException) {
            println(ex.message)
        } catch (ex: BadPaddingException) {
            println(ex.message)
        } catch (ex: InvalidKeyException) {
            println(ex.message)
        } catch (ex: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
            println(ex.message)
        } catch (ex: NoSuchPaddingException) {
            println(ex.message)
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            println(ex.message)
        }
        return null
    }
```